# Perform XMLHttpRequest in inject js in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I need to perform an XMLHttpRequest in one of my inject javascript file (not in the content_script js) because I use a library that need to be inject in the DOM for work.

This is my **content.js** script:

```
function addScript(src) {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = chrome.extension.getURL(src);
  (document.body || document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
  return script;
}

function addStyle(src) {
  var css = document.createElement('link');
  css.rel = "stylesheet";
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.href = chrome.extension.getURL(src);
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(css);
  return css;
}

addStyle('dist/assets/css/style.css');
addScript("dist/js/app.js");
```

If I try to do my XMLHttpRequest in this file its work!

But I had to do that in a part of my **app.js**

```
findOrder(order){
    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      console.log(xhr);
      xhr.open("GET", "https://111111.ngrok.io/", true);

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
        }
      }

      xhr.send();
    });
 }
```

And this is part of my **manifest.js**:

```
{ 
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "https://*.ngrok.io/*",
    "*://mail.google.com/*"
],

"content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": [ "*://mail.google.com/*" ],
      "js": [
          "src/js/content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],

"web_accessible_resources":[
    "dist/assets/css/style.css",
    "dist/js/app.js",
    "dist/imgs/*.png"
]
}
```

Someone can help me?

I try to add an `CustomEvent` and `dispatchEvent` my **app.js** and an `addEventListener` in my **content.js** but I can't pass a callback to return the request response.

Thanks in advance!

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: To pass data between page context and content script context you can use DOM messaging via window.dispatchEvent with CustomEvent constructor.

Comment: I create the CustomEvent and dispatchEvent in app.js and the addEventListener in content.js. this do the xhr but how can I return the result to the app.js??

Comment: content script adds a listener for `some-unique-event-name` and app.js does dispatchEvent with that event name and `{detail: yourdata}` as the second parameter, see the documentation for CustomEvent constructor.

Comment: I know i set the parametes for perform the xhr, but if I add a function in detail for callback, in the `addEventListener` detail is _null_. This works: `{detail:{method:'GET', url: 'url', params: par}}`. This give me NULL in the listener (in `console.log(e.detail)`): `{detail:{method:'GET', url: 'url', params: par, foo: function() {...} }}`

Comment: I don't know what's your actual code so I can't help you.